# Manually setting annotation on generated migration using EF and MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have a property that is in my class that is not the primary key that I want to auto increment. The primary key is a GUID so I can still use the auto increment function on another column in the table. Also I can't change the primary key to int as the GUID key is defined in a base class. I can manually add the `.Annotation("MySQL:AutoIncrement", true)` to the property in the generated migration but I'm concern about editing the migration causing future issues. I found what would be the answer via the `.AddAnnotation(,)` method but it doesn't created the desired results.

Also `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` doesn't produce the desired result.

I was hoping this:

```
builder.Entity<Editor>().Property(p => p.CreatorId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Throw;
builder.Entity<Editor>().Property(p => p.CreatorId).Metadata.AddAnnotation("MySQL:AutoIncrement", true);
```

Would make this:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "editor",
    columns: table => new
    {
       CreatorId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false).Annotation("MySQL:AutoIncrement", true)
       ...
```

MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore: 8.0.18.0

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

After using DotPeek to look at the code for MySql.Data.EntityFramework it seems to not be possible to reach the desired affect with fluentApi or attributes as it will only add the annotation if it's the primary key. Regardless of if it's possible in the database.